# Image of a projective variety under a morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-varieties, morphism

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of projective varieties. If $X=\cup_{i=1}^n X_i$ is the irreducible decomposition of $X$ does the following hold? $$f(X)=f\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n f(X_i)$$

whereby the $f(X_i)$ are the irreducible components of $f(X)$ in the ambient target space $Y$?

My belief is that this is likely to hold due to the preservation of irreducibility of morphisms and the fact that projective morphisms map closed sets onto closed sets. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What you have written is just a set-theoretic equality which is obviously true. Are you asking whether the irreducible components of $f(X)$ are the $f(X_i)$? What is true is that $f(X_i)$ is an irreducible component for *some* indexes $i$, but it may happen that $f(X_j)$ is strictly contained in $f(X_i)$ and thus $f(X_j)$ is not an irreducible component.

Comment: thank you for the kind response! I must apologise - I was perhaps a little unclear in my question formulation however you have interpreted it just as I meant; I shall edit it now to reflect this.